# FIFO match first stock buys to first sells sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, fifo, cursors

I have data that looks like this:

[Stock buys and sells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftI1Q.png)

I need a query to apply the FIFO method to the Buys and Sells so I get a table that looks like this:
[FIFO Buys and Sells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ao2Qm.png)

I want to be able to match the first buy/s to the first sells with buys on the left and sells on the right. If there is no sell then Nulls should be applied on the right and if there is no buy then nulls should be applied on the left. The brokerage transaction key can be used as the order in which the trades occurred. This is what I've tried so far. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
SELECT  a.ACCT_ID, a.Trade_Date_Key, a.Brokerage_Transaction_Key, a.Buy_Sell_Code, a.Principal_Amt, a.Security_Quantity
     , (a.Security_Quantity + b.Security_Quantity) CUMULATIVE_POSITION
     , a.SHARE_PRICE
     , (A.Principal_Amt + B.Principal_Amt) CUMULATIVE_VALUE
from #TRANSACTIONS_WITH_RANK a
     left join #TRANSACTIONS_WITH_RANK b 
     on a.acct_id = b.acct_id and a.rank = b.rank + 1
ORDER BY BROKERAGE_TRANSACTION_KEY
```

Answer (score 0):

In your question you mention matching the first buy(s) with the first sell(s), but your example output seems to ignore that part.  Here's an example of how to do if you want to match the first buy(s) to first sell(s) based on the `Acct_ID` and `Trade_Date`

```
SELECT buy.*, sell.*
FROM #TRANSACTIONS_WITH_RANK buy
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT MIN(Trade_Date) Trade_Date
        FROM #TRANSACTIONS_WITH_RANK
        WHERE Buy_Sell_Code = 'B'
        GROUP BY Acct_ID
    ) TDateBuy
    ON buy.Trade_Date = TDateBuy.Trade_Date
    FULL OUTER JOIN #TRANSACTIONS_WITH_RANK sell
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT MIN(Trade_Date) Trade_Date
            FROM #TRANSACTIONS_WITH_RANK
            WHERE Buy_Sell_Code = 'S'
            GROUP BY Acct_ID
        ) TDateSell
        ON sell.Trade_Date = TDateSell.Trade_Date
    ON buy.Acct_ID = sell.Acct_ID
```

---

**EDIT**: after seeing OP's comment I have changed the query

```
SELECT 
    buy.Acct_ID, buy.Trade_Date, buy.Brokerage_Transaction_Key, buy.Buy_Sell_Code, buy.Principal_Amt, buy.Security_Quantity, 
    sell.Acct_ID, sell.Trade_Date, sell.Brokerage_Transaction_Key, sell.Buy_Sell_Code, sell.Principal_Amt, sell.Security_Quantity
FROM (
        SELECT wr.*, MIN(TransKey) TransKey -- This is the value of the Sell to be joined
        FROM #TRANSACTIONS_WITH_RANK wr
            LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                SELECT MIN(Brokerage_Transaction_Key) TransKey, Acct_ID
                FROM (
                        SELECT 
                            tr.*, 
                            (
                                SELECT MAX(Brokerage_Transaction_Key) --Purpose is to give outer query value to GROUP on
                                FROM #TRANSACTIONS_WITH_RANK 
                                WHERE Buy_Sell_Code = 'B' 
                                    AND Acct_ID = tr.Acct_ID
                                    AND Brokerage_Transaction_Key < tr.Brokerage_Transaction_Key
                            ) MaxLesserKey
                        FROM #TRANSACTIONS_WITH_RANK tr
                    ) data
                WHERE Buy_Sell_Code = 'S'
                GROUP BY Acct_ID, MaxLesserKey
            ) MinSell
            ON wr.Acct_ID = MinSell.Acct_ID
                AND wr.Brokerage_Transaction_Key < MinSell.TransKey
        WHERE Buy_Sell_Code = 'B'
        GROUP BY wr.Acct_ID, Trade_Date, Brokerage_Transaction_Key, Buy_Sell_Code, Principal_Amt, Security_Quantity
    ) buy
    FULL OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT wr.*, MIN(MinBuy.TransKey) TransKey -- This is the value of the Buy to be joined
        FROM #TRANSACTIONS_WITH_RANK wr
            LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                SELECT MIN(Brokerage_Transaction_Key) TransKey, Acct_ID
                FROM (
                        SELECT 
                            tr.*,
                            (
                                SELECT MAX(Brokerage_Transaction_Key) --Purpose is to give outer query a value to GROUP on
                                FROM #TRANSACTIONS_WITH_RANK
                                WHERE Buy_Sell_Code = 'S'
                                    AND Brokerage_Transaction_Key < tr.Brokerage_Transaction_Key
                            ) MaxLesserKey
                        FROM #TRANSACTIONS_WITH_RANK tr
                    ) data
                WHERE Buy_Sell_Code = 'B'
                GROUP BY Acct_ID, MaxLesserKey
            ) MinBuy
            ON wr.Acct_ID = MinBuy.Acct_ID
                AND wr.Brokerage_Transaction_Key < MinBuy.TransKey
        WHERE Buy_Sell_Code = 'S'
        GROUP BY wr.Acct_ID, Trade_Date, Brokerage_Transaction_Key, Buy_Sell_Code, Principal_Amt, Security_Quantity
    ) sell
    ON buy.TransKey = sell.Brokerage_Transaction_Key
        OR sell.TransKey = buy.Brokerage_Transaction_Key
```

Basically what this does is grab all Buy(s) and their matching Sell `Brokerage_Transaction_Key` (`TransKey`) and does a `FULL OUTER JOIN` (`NULL`s out the Buy or Sell side when there are no opposite matching transactions) to the set of Sell(s) and their matching Buy `Brokerage_Transaction_Key` (`TransKey`).
The `TransKey` is the smallest `Brokerage_Transaction_Key` of the opposite `Buy_Sell_Code` for each group of Buy(s)/Sell(s). This will give you first Sell to first Buy(s) or first Buy to first Sell(s) per group of transactions for a particular `Acct_ID`.  The `MaxLesserKey` field is there to just to give the `TransKey` query a value to `GROUP` on

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear, the brokerage_transaction_key is a unique field that indicates the order of the trade. So it needs to be used to indicate which buy came before which sell in each account.

Comment: I understand now.  Is this only for wanted for the first buy/sell set?  i.e. An Account has 3 buys matched with a single sell (call it `set1`), then at a later date they have another 2 buys before they have a sell (call it `set2`). Should `set2` show up as another set of buy/sells in the data or should it still only show `set1`?

Comment: You're correct it should be set 2. The security quantity on the buy side needs to match the security quantity on the sell side if that makes sense.

Comment: To clarify, should it be `set2` only or both sets?

Comment: Both sets. So if the first 3 buys are 100, 200, 100, and the first sell is 400, that would be set1, and if the next buy is 100 and the next two sells are 50 and 50, that would be set2.

Comment: I have edited my answer. The reason for the `MaxLesserKey` field is to match buy/sell keys with their actual buy/sell set and not with all buy/sell sets for a particular `Acct_ID`.